# How are hex codes converted to RGB 255 values?

Tags: css, hex, ascii

I know that 0 through F represent 0-15, and hex codes are split into 3 groups of two digit hexadecimals, but how is the value 0 through 255 reached with these two digits for R, G, and B?
For example #FF FF FF is #1515 1515 1515, it's displayed as white and equal to R=255, G=255, B=255, but how do two 15's equal 255? Multiplied they're only 225.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the number base.

(FF)_16 = 15*16^1 + 15*16^0 = (255)_10

FF are in base 16 while your 255 are in base 10. so you will need to apply base conversion to get the number in the other base.

you may wanna read up more about it from [this link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html)

Answer (score 2):

For `# 15 15` you don't  do 15*15. As the number is **`hex`** `(base 16)` not **`decimal`** `(base 10)` you'll do 16<sup>1</sup>*15 + 16<sup>0</sup>*15 which will evnetually come out to be 255.

Decimal `255` in different bases is represented as

- **Binary** (base 2) `11111111` = 2<sup>7</sup>*1 + 2<sup>6</sup>*1 + 2<sup>5</sup>*1 + ...
- **Octal** (base 8)  `377` = 8<sup>2</sup>*3 + 8<sup>1</sup>*7 + 8<sup>0</sup>*7

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misunderstand what is meant by 0x0~0xF representing 0~15. 0xF does not represent the number 15; it represents a single digit with a value of 15. So 0x10 is not the number 1 concatenated with a 0 to produce 10 (this wouldn't make sense anyway, as 0xA is 10); rather, you might want to think of it as having been counted up to from 0x0.

0x0 (0), 0x1 (1), 0x2 (2), 0x3 (3), 0x4 (4), 0x5 (5), 0x6 (6), 0x7 (7), 0x8 (8), 0x9 (9), 0xA (10), 0xB (11), 0xC (12), 0xD (13), 0xE (14), 0xF (15), 0x10 (16).